# Proportional editing creates rough edges around shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a simple mountain with proportional editing, and I'm finding that it's creating unusual faces around the edges of the surface.  What I was hoping to do was to create a bell curve-like surface that is smooth around the entire surface.  However, what's actually happening, is it's becoming almost like an umbrella:

[image]

What rule does this follow, and is there a setting that can be changed to create more faces (almost like a subdivision, except on the proportional editing)?

I did use the Connected proportional editing mode, mainly because if I use Projected it comes up with a different kind of shape based on the projection of the camera (which seems fitting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proportional editing is set to connected.

[image]

You can change it to Projected (2D) to get your desired result.

[image]

Comment: See edit.  The reason I didn't use projected is because it creates an odd shape that makes a non-symmetrical mountain depending on the view projection.  I need a fully symmetrical shape across each axis, with the same weight on each side.

Comment: You should just enable basic Proportional Editing by clicking on **Enable**.

Comment: You can change the falloff, but creating more faces is not possible. What you can do as a workaround is just edit it a few times and decrease the radius and how high you drag it. That would decrease the deform of faces on the bottom.